# IDEA doesn't see method, generarated by custom annotation processor

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, annotations

I have a project build with gradle and imported to Intellij-Idea.

There's a custom annotation processor, which adds a variable and a method to class.

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes(value = "my.anno.SignedSource")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_7)
public class SignedSourceAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    //business logics
}
```

Source file, using this annotation looks like:

```
@SignedSource
public class MyClass{
    private void someMethod(){
        this.generatedMethod();
    }
}
```

After the build from command line (gradlew clean build), I get valid .class file. It compiles perfectly from command-line.

```
@SignedSource
public class MyClass{

    public void generatedMethod(){
        //some business code
    }

    private void someMethod(){
        this.generatedMethod();
    }
}
```

However, MyClass doesn't compile in Intellij IDEA, generated method is not found.

Processor is registered in

```
 META-INF/service/javax.annotation.processing.Processor
```

Annotation Processing is enabled.

[image]

What am I missing?